# populate google map from dynamic JSON C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I have the following JSON:

```
{
"request_time": "2017-01-01T20:21:26+00:00",
"stations": [
{
  "station_code": "MAT",
  "atcocode": null,
  "tiploc_code": "MATLOCK",
  "name": "Matlock",
  "mode": "train",
  "longitude": -1.558911,
  "latitude": 53.138406,
  "distance": 221
},
{
  "station_code": "MTB",
  "atcocode": null,
  "tiploc_code": "MATLCKB",
  "name": "Matlock Bath",
  "mode": "train",
  "longitude": -1.556759,
  "latitude": 53.122353,
  "distance": 1784
   }
 ]
}
```

I am trying to pin the station names, longitude and latitude to a google map. I am getting a error but with no description of where the error is. This is the back end C# code:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("window"))
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "window", "CreateMarker();", true);
        }

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public MAPS[] BindMapMarker()
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr;
        List<MAPS> lstMarkers = new List<MAPS>();
        try
        {

            string json = get_web_content("https://transportapi.com/v3/uk/train/stations/near.json?app_id=03bf8009&app_key=d9307fd91b0247c607e098d5effedc97&lat=53.13838&lon=-1.5556&rpp=3");

            dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            dynamic DepartTimes = array.stations;

            foreach (var item in DepartTimes)
            {
                //dt.Columns.Add("LocationName");
                dt.Columns.Add("Location");
                dt.Columns.Add("Latitude");
                dt.Columns.Add("Longitude");

                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Location"] = item["name"];
                dr["Latitude"] = item["latitude"];
                dr["Longitude"] = item["longitude"];


                dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            }



            foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows)
            {
                MAPS objMAPS = new MAPS();
                objMAPS.LocationName = dtrow[0].ToString();
                objMAPS.Latitude = dtrow[0].ToString();
                objMAPS.Longitude = dtrow[1].ToString();
                lstMarkers.Add(objMAPS);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }


        return lstMarkers.ToArray();
    }



    public class MAPS
    {
        public string LocationName;
        public string Latitude;
        public string Longitude;
    }

    public string get_web_content(string url)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string output = reader.ReadToEnd();
        response.Close();

        return output;
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: One thing that might be blowing up is that you are creating your columns multiple times by putting that code in the body of the foreach loop.  You should only be adding these once before processing the results from the API.  However, why are you putting them in a DataTable only to transfer them to a collection of objects just below there?

Comment: I am putting them into a data table in order to add each row of data to a google map, is it not necessary to add the JSON data to a DataTable?

Comment: Where are you adding them to a Google map?  In the JavaScript that processes the results of the web method?  If so, then no, adding them to a DataTable is an unnecessary middle step.  Just use one foreach loop to assign the data in `DepartTimes` straight to `MAP` objects and return the list of those.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome.  If this solved your problem, please accept the answer I added below.  Many thanks!

Comment: Look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

One thing that might be blowing up is that you are creating your columns multiple times by putting that code in the body of the foreach loop. You should only be adding these once before processing the results from the API.

Where are you adding them to a Google map? In the JavaScript that processes the results of the web method? If so, then no, adding them to a DataTable is an unnecessary middle step. Just use one foreach loop to assign the data in DepartTimes straight to MAP objects and return the list of those.

Answer (score 0):

something like this then?

```
 foreach (var item in DepartTimes)
            {
                MAPS objMAPS = new MAPS();
                objMAPS.LocationName = item["name"].ToString();
                objMAPS.Latitude = item["latitude"].ToString();
                objMAPS.Longitude = item["longitude"].ToString();
                lstMarkers.Add(objMAPS);
             }
```

Comment: Yup that's what I was thinking.